# How to make a dict of multiple lists in python?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, list-comprehension

I want to make a list of dicts that have the following structure,

```
[{'Business' : 'Attorney' , 'Website text' : '(one line from the loaded file)'}, {'Business' : 'Attorney' , 'Website text' : '(one line from the loaded file)'}, ...]
```

However at the moment i only have a csv file consisting of the website text.

Below i have attempted to somehow create lists of the same length as my website text file, then zip them and create a dict from that. I have been unable to find information on here when it comes to creating a dict from more that 2 lists.

```
with open('attorneys text.csv') as data_file:
    attorneys = list(line for line in data_file)

website = []
business = []
classes = []
for l in range(len(attorneys)):
    website.append("Website text")

for k in range(len(attorneys)):
    business.append("Business")

for i in range(len(attorneys)):
    classes.append("Attorney")

data = dict(zip((business, classes, website, attorneys)))
```

I am well aware of the ugliness of the try as well...

Comment: you should share a small example of csv input file and expected output. I see a lot of room for improvement, but that looks more like a question for codereview...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The input of the csv file is just a string per line as described, and the output wanted is the one presented first in the question. Do you mean a more specific example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the only difference is the text, you can do the following:

```
with open('attorneys text.csv') as data_file:
    data = [{'Business':'Attorney', 'Website text':line} for line in data_file]
```

The `'Business':'Attorney'` pair will be the same for each dictionary, while the value corresponding to `'Website text'` will be the data from your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict:)

```
from collections import defaultdict
s = ["Business", "Attorney", "Website text"]
data = defaultdict(list)

data[s[0]].append(business)
data[s[1]].append(classes)
data[s[2]].append(website)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i would do:

```
data = []

with open('attorneys text.csv') as data_file:
  for line in data_file
    row = { "Business": "Attorney", "Website text": line}
    data.append(row)
```

I don t know if i understood well what you want to do